# applymap() does not work on Pandas MultiIndex Slice

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have an hierarchical dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,6),
              columns=[['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
                       ['mean', 'max', 'avg']*2],
              index=pd.date_range('20000103', periods=6))
```

I want to apply a function to all values under the columns `A`. I can set the value to something:

```
df.loc[slice(None), 'A'] = 1
```

Easy enough. Now, instead of assigning a value, if I want to apply a mapping to this `MultiIndex` slice, it does not work.

For example, let me apply a simple formatting statement:

```
df.loc[slice(None), 'A'].applymap('{:.2f}'.format)
```

This step works fine. However, I cannot assign this to the original df:

```
df.loc[slice(None), 'A'] = df.loc[slice(None), 'A'].applymap('{:.2f}'.format)
```

Everything turns into a `NaN`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try this: `df['A'] = df.loc[slice(None), 'A'].applymap('{:.2f}'.format)`? Actually `df['A'] = df['A'].round(2)` - should be much faster

Comment: `'df['A'] = df.loc[slice(None), 'A'].applymap()` worked. Thanks. Happy to accept if you want to post it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a couple of ways:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].applymap('{:.2f}'.format)
```

or (this will keep the original dtype)

```
df['A'] = df['A'].round(2)
```

or as a string

```
df['A'] = df['A'].round(2).astype(str)
```

Comment: It seems you need the `slice(None)` on the operation side.

Comment: @saud, i've tested it without `slice(None)` - it works properly (at least for Pandas 0.19.2)